# Standard symbology for representing IT infrastructure?

Tags: networking

I'm writing a CMDB type application in which I hope to model connectivity as well as the conventional stuff you would find in such a system.

Is there a standard set of glyphs used to represent components (hub, switch, router, server, NAS....)?

I am aware of the Cisco symbol set - but this is somewhat restricted and (IMHO) more like a clip art library than a design tool. Archimate is too abstract.

Comment: AFAIK There is no industry standard. Most companies seem to develop their own internal standards. As you say most networking people will recognise Cisco iconography and many architects  like Archimate and frequently I have also used vendor supplied Visio stencils. Or save yourself from grief and simply use text labels and [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php)

Comment: I don't think what symbols matter so long as it is consistent and accurate - how would this look sketched on a whiteboard?   Provide as many views as necessary, network physical and logical, hypervisor,  VMs, databases, applications.  Text labels on boxes can be functional, although yes icons are nice.

Answer (score 0):

While my question was posted and gathering few responses, I continued my search and came across a paper and some follow up up work from Georgia Southern University describing the the [SANDS](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://iacis.org/iis/2008/S2008_967.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj5nuHvwrzPAhWFmh4KHaekDSYQFghNMBE&usg=AFQjCNGb00oA816OszaEl4Qhh93Y9ROqkQ&sig2=0ldtpoS5hnfHhHNEfG-4FQ) model. The paper linked here, far more eloquently describes the problem domain. However the proposed solution, IMHO, leaves a lot to be desired:

- describing a honey pot as a single node strikes me as somewhat innappropriate.
- again in relation to a honeypot, using a visual metaphor representing a verbal metaphor for a device of specific intent seems a stretch
- re-purposing the symbol used for a diode to represent a firewall has some merit, however its pre-existing semantics do not completely describe the behaviour of a firewall while having an explicit and well defined functionality within an electrnic circuit. Its use as a symbol is further undermined by the potential requirement to describe [data diodes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidirectional_network) within the model.
- a later evolution of the model, SANDL also attempts to define cpu and memory (which I believe should not be described in the domain)
- Again IMHO, the model includes devices which are redundant (a fax is a printer, scanner, and network interface hence does not require its own node type)
- no consideration, other than the physical connection, is given to the edges connecting the nodes; there are (for example) many logical dependencies within a computer network.
- while a camera and printer are examples of a sensor and an effector, even when this paper was written there were many more of these classes of devices in use on networks
- the representation of a functional aggregate is not a node itself but a bounding box drawn around nodes, somewhat undermining any attempt to create views of the network at progressive levels of detail.

It's starting to look like I may have to start [from scratch.](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png)